# Trying to filter SQL results by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database for a library and am trying to write a query to return all the books that have not been checked out for five years

it should produce something like this...

```
 isbn |        title        |    author     
------+---------------------+---------------
  222 | The Art of the Deal | Trump
  444 | Im a cool guy       | Forrest Stone
(2 rows)
```

I have a `books` table,

```
library6=# SELECT * FROM books;
 isbn |                 title                 |    author     
------+---------------------------------------+---------------
  111 | Harry Potter and the Sorcerer’s Stone | JK Rowlings
  222 | The Art of the Deal                   | Trump
  333 | to catch a crook                      | Robert Muller
  444 | Im a cool guy                         | Forrest Stone
  555 | rich i am                             | Bill Gates
(5 rows)
```

I have a `transactions` table,

```
library6=# SELECT * FROM transactions;
 id | checked_out_date | checked_in_date | user_id | isbn 
----+------------------+-----------------+---------+------
  1 | 2016-01-01       | 2016-02-01      |       1 |  111
  2 | 2016-02-02       | 2016-03-02      |       2 |  111
  3 | 2016-03-03       | 2016-05-03      |       3 |  111
  5 | 2017-11-29       | 2017-12-04      |       5 |  555
  6 | 2017-11-28       | 2017-12-05      |       1 |  333
  4 | 2017-12-06       | 2017-12-09      |       4 |  111
  5 | 2010-01-01       | 2010-01-02      |       1 |  222
(7 rows)
```

So far I have tried, it properly joins the two tables and returns the book that has never been checked out but misses the book that was checked out 5+ yeas ago.

```
library6=# SELECT b.title,b.author , b.isbn FROM transactions t
RIGHT OUTER JOIN books b ON t.isbn = b.isbn 
WHERE   t.isbn IS NULL;
     title     |    author     | isbn 
---------------+---------------+------
 Im a cool guy | Forrest Stone |  444
(1 row)
```

so I then tried

```
library6=# SELECT b.title, t.isbn FROM transactions t
RIGHT OUTER JOIN books b ON t.isbn = b.isbn 
WHERE t.checked_out_date >= DATEADD(year, 5, '2017/12/09') AS DateAdd   OR  
t.isbn IS NULL;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 3: ...hecked_out_date >= DATEADD(year, 5, '2017/12/09') AS DateAdd...
```

**ideally** I would use `timestamp` to automatically generate the current date, but one step at a time.

Answer (score 2):

```
library6=# 
SELECT b.title, b.isbn,b.author ,max(t.checked_out_date) 
    FROM transactions t
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN books b ON t.isbn = b.isbn 
    group by b.isbn, b.title
    having max(t.checked_out_date) <= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 
    years')
```

PostgreSQL does not provide dateadd function

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
select isbn, title, max(checked_out_date)
from books join transactions on books.isbn = transactions.isbn
group by isbn, title
having max(checked_out_date) <= dateadd(year, 5, current_date)
```

I don't work with postgresql so I don't know it's equivalent to dateadd.